# Solo artist pseudonyms and tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Many solo musicians use (several) names/pseudonyms. How should we handle the tags for these artists?

- One tag per person?
- One tag per name?
- One tag per name, but all would be synonyms for a canonical tag?

Example: [Norman Cook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Cook)

He was born as "**Quentin Leo Cook**", is now called "**Norman Quentin Cook**" (but more often "**Norman Cook**"), is very well known under his stage name "**Fatboy Slim**", well known as "**The Brighton Port Authority**", also known  as "**Son of a Cheeky Boy**" … [and has many more names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Cook#Bands_and_pseudonyms).

Comment: Synonyms for the major names makes sense to me

Comment: Are you trying to use tags like search terms? Major artist tags should be OK, but for others, that is what the search engine is for.

Comment: Springsteen too.  No need for *springsteen*, *bruce-springsteen*, *bruce-springsteen-and-the-e-street-band*, etc...   As well as John (Cougar) Mellencamp.

Answer (score 8):

I believe we should have a tag for the most known name of the artist.

Like, John Francis Anthony Pastorius III was famously known as Jaco Pastorius.

That is why I created a tag [jaco-pastorius](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jaco-pastorius) and not [john-francis-anthony-pastorius-iii](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-francis-anthony-pastorius-iii).

We could created synonyms for the artists' other names, but I don't see much point in creating a tag for every pseudonym they have every created.

If they have become famous under two or more pseudonyms, then yes why not.

Comment: I created an [example question](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/387/47). On this project "The BPA", "Norman Cook" is listed as artist, not "Fatboy Slim". But the pseudonym "Fatboy Slim" is (most likely) the most known name of the artist Norman Cook ([used as a tag](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatboy-slim) for the questions that are about works of Fatboy Slim). So you’d propose to use [tag:fatboy-slim] even for this example question, although neither the project (The BPA) nor the artist (Norman Cook) refer to "Fatboy Slim" in this context?

Comment: @unor I'd like to see only one master tag per artist.  In Norman Cook's case, I think the name "Norman Cook" is the most inclusive name, so I'd say make "norman-cook" the master tag, and make "fatboy-slim" a synonym tag.  It's a weak preference, though.  "fatboy-slim" would be okay for the master tag as well.  But I think there is value in having only one tag and having all questions about Norman Cook grouped together.

Answer (score 2):

Tags, I believe, should be emergent. There's no real point in pre-creating tags for artists and aliases before someone has come along to ask about them. When they do, either they'll use the existing tag (which is great), they'll create a new tag for a different alias (at which point the community can retag, or create a synonym), or leave it untagged (if they don't have the rep to create a tag), which, again, will fall to the community to tag.

Either way, I think we should see how people tag.

Comment: Agreed. An index without content is meaningless.

Comment: My intention was not to discuss if we should create tags proactively (AFAIK tags without questions get deleted automatically unless they get a tag description also), but which way to follow *when* we need them. I created several artist tags on this site, but I think a community decision is important for those cases where a solo artist has several pseudonyms (under which music is published).

Answer (score 0):

I think that if someone uses a specific pseudonym, this actually **helps** to answer the question as the question might be closely related and/or depend on the particular pseudonym used.

For example, music producer Terre Thaemlitz is also known as [DJ Sprinkles](http://www.discogs.com/artist/51192-DJ-Sprinkles). Some people might now a lot about his musical output as *Terre Thaemlitz* (ambient, experimental music), but others might know a lot more about his *DJ Sprinkles* releases (deep house) and not know much about his other work.

To be honest, I don't think this should be an issue, everything should be fine.