# Can we synonymize the tags [fatboy-slim] and [norman-cook]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonyms

The musician Norman Cook is also popularly known by the pseudonym Fatboy Slim. We currently have the tags [norman-cook](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norman-cook) as well as [fatboy-slim](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatboy-slim); there are 2 questions with the former tag, 4 questions with the latter, and 0 questions with both.

As per the policy decided [here](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/a/127/3955), can we make one of the tags a synonym of the other?

I am not partial towards any particular direction. (Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatboy_Slim) is titled Fatboy Slim, but the contents of the article consistently use "Cook" to refer to the artist, so that's confusing.)

For clarity, the linked policy is the highest scoring answer on the question [Solo artist pseudonyms and tags](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/3955), which says that there should be a single tag for an artist, namely the most popular / well-known name, and other well-known pseudonyms should be made synonyms of it. (The answer also advises against rushing to create synonyms for every possible pseudonym<sup>[1]</sup>.)

Also, note that there is another related tag [the-bpa](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-bpa) for The Brighton Port Authority, but it is not fully clear to me whether this should be viewed as a band or as a pseudonym of Norman Cook. (Wikipedia treats it as an [act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatboy_Slim#2008%E2%80%932012:_The_Brighton_Port_Authority), but [@JohnnyBones](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/53/johnny-bones) argues that it is essentially a solo project of Cook<sup>[2]</sup>). So, I prefer to err on the side of caution and suggest keeping them separate.

---

<sup>[1]: Question: [Musician with the most one-off aliases](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/6144/3955)</sup>
<sup>[2]: Answer: [What or who is The Brighton Port Authority?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/2317/3955)</sup>